# POSTGRESQL- Make foreign key column point to another table

Tags: database, foreign-keys, psql

I'm using psql and I want to change one of the columns of my table.
At the moment this column is a foreign key of Table 2 but I would like to make it point to Table 3.

Is this possible or should I delete the column and add a new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to add & remove the column. You can remove/disable the constraint to one table and add it for the other table.

The command for doing the former is:

```
alter table Table1 drop constraint if exists name_of_constraint_on_Table_1_column
```

The command for doing the latter is:

```
alter table Table1
add constraint name_of_constraint_on_Table_1_column
foreign key (column) references Table3 (other_column) match full
```

You need to find the name of the foreign key constraint if you haven't named it explicitly. You can do so via the `\d` command:

```
\d Table1
```

You should read about [`alter table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html) cause there's a lot of things you can do to change the table.

Comment: What's is `match full`? Why not use `deferrable initially deferred` instead?